# certain folders doesn't update in CVS

Tags: cvs

I've got a problem while updating folders from CVS, while all the folders in the CVS updating, only certain folders like "output" doesn't

This is the command I'm using:

```
WShell.run "cvs -q -d :sspi:davids@zeus:/SVIS update SHClientServer",1,true
```

This is the CVS UI command that is executed:

In C:\Build\VS2012Build\SHClientServer:

```
"C:\Program Files\CVSNT\cvs.exe" -q update -P -d CVSROOT=:sspi:davids@zeus:/SVIS
```

But if I do a CVS update with the UI, meaning right click on the folder and update, everything is updating correctly

My question is, why doesn't it update certain folders, and how can I make the CVS update "by force" ?

Comment: Are files in this directory tracked by CVS? Likely not, because it, well, output.

Comment: but if i do a CVS update with the UI, meaning right click on the folder and update, everything is updating correctly

Comment: You haven't answered if files are tracked. Ok, let's try mindreading game - try adding `-d` after `update`, it will enable updating newly added directories (directories that was added by new commits after you've initially checkouted).

Comment: all files are being tracked, i answered that when i said the update worked if using the UI, i tried putting the -d after update, nothing worked

Comment: Does your shell client run with the same rights/user as your UI? Does the folder have the same user/group/rights? What happens if you set that "output" to 777?

Comment: Changed the folder to 777, nothing got updated, there were no new "Output" created.

Comment: How to i change the Permission of the shell client ?

Comment: You sure that both directories are in the same repository? Check `CVS/Repository` file contents for both directories. Also, seeing output of `cvs up` in root directory would be nice - i'm sure i'll report permission problems if you have one (not that i believe it anyway)

Comment: This the UI command :

In C:\Build\VS2012Build\SHClientServer: "C:\Program Files\CVSNT\cvs.exe" -q update -P -d
CVSROOT=:sspi:davids@zeus:/SVIS